# Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i need to return data from tow api in angular 8 .

i create this resolver :

```
export class AccessLevelResolve implements Resolve<any>{

constructor(private accessLevel: AccessLevelService) { }

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    let id = +route.paramMap.get('id');

    const getControllerList = this.accessLevel.getAll().pipe(
        map(
            res => {
                if (res) {
                    return res.date;
                }
            }
        )
    )

    const getRoleAccessRole = this.accessLevel.getAllWithId(id).pipe(
        map(
            res => {
                if (res) {
                    return res.date;
                }
            }
        )
    )
   return forkJoin(getControllerList, getRoleAccessRole).subscribe(res => {
        return {
            controllerList: res[0],
            accessRoleList: res[1]
        }
    }
    )

}
```

but it show me this error :

> Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.

**whats the problem ??? how can i solve this problem ??**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't subscribe in your resolver, you return the observable and angular subscribes:

```
return forkJoin(getControllerList, getRoleAccessRole).pipe(map(res => {
    return {
        controllerList: res[0],
        accessRoleList: res[1]
    }
}))
```